# how to model the transient response of a function in 1D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, partial-differential-equations

I have a fairly simple problem. Here is the statement:

I know $f(x,t)$ over a period of time. I want to model its evolution, i.e. $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$. But the transient response is very "noisy" because the approximated $f(x,t)$ is not a good approximation.

How can I model $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$ to a fairly accurate manner?

Here is a 3D plot, may it help to visualize.

[image: The evolution of a function]

Comment: In general you are asking to evaluate something which is "unstable", i.e. for a given tolerance of accuracy in the derivative of $f$ calculated through numeric differentiation of values of $f$, you need far more accuracy than that tolerance in the values of $f$ itself.

Comment: i actually realize that. typically some sort of regularizations are applied. i tried, it approximates OK for the first spatial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}$, but the temporal derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$ doesn't look good at all.

Comment: Have you thought of just solving a new PDE for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$?

Comment: yeah, that's right... I want to derive an analytical fit for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ given the evolution :)

Comment: No, I don't mean using your solution to the PDE for $f$ to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. I mean solving a new, different PDE to compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your phrase 'solving a new, different PDE'. are you saying coming up with my own right hand side (RHS) of the equation $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = ?$. If that's what you mean, then no, I haven't. I don't see how to do it. As far as I know, the PDE is something like $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t} = g(f(x,t))$, where $g$ is a prescribed function. depending on this $g$ it could be hyperbolic, parabolic, or others...

Comment: Say your PDE was the wave equation, $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$. Another PDE solved by that same $u$ is $u_{ttt}=u_{xxt}$, so $v_{tt}=v_{xx}$ where $v=u_t$. So you can in principle solve a new wave equation (with different boundary conditions) to get $u_t$. Of course I'm assuming you have all the regularity you want. The one major obstacle to this is that you have the initial condition for just $v$ but not for $v_t$. But perhaps you could estimate that initial condition from your already-known solution for $u$...

Comment: that's a very interesting thought. but at the end of the day, you still have to model $f_t$ somehow, right? or $f_{tt}$? at least 1 partial derivative wrt $t$?

Comment: Sure...but assuming you can get a PDE like I wrote (which is not trivial; it works in the linear case but probably not otherwise) and you can resolve this issue about the initial condition, then you should be able to do something very similar to what you did to obtain values of $f$ to obtain values of $f_t$.